# How to handle app redirection issue of Iphone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, macos

I have an app installed on iPhone device so when user hits the web URL and if app is already installed on the device then automatically redirects to the app otherwise open the Play Store app URL can we handle this.?

I already implemented set timeout logic but it didn't work with any other solution for the same because of iPhone they keep asking popup that why I can't handle this from code side